# aws_route53_record - " An argument named "alias" is not expected here"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "my_route_53" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.my_zone.zone_id
  name    = ""
  type    = "A"
  
  alias = {
    name    = local.my_domain
    zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.my_zone.zone_id
  }
}
```

This is returning an error of `An argument named "alias" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "alias"?`

I am using `Terraform v1.3.4`

The error is completely unexpected because I can see from the docs (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record) that it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the `=` sign, this is how the code block should look like (example from the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#alias-record)):

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "my_route_53" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.my_zone.zone_id
  name    = ""
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name    = local.my_domain
    zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.my_zone.zone_id
  }
}
```